# C++: Multiple consoles running in one project?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

So basically what I want, is having two consoles running the same time, interacting with eachother and sharing the same variables in Visual C++. Any ideas?

Comment: "A process can be associated with only one console". Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Complicated solution: Multiple processes and IPC.

Comment: And what if there are 2 projects? Is there any way to "combine" them?

Comment: It doesn´t matter how many VS projects you have. And no, you can´t "combine" them.

Comment: You can just start 2 processes and have them communicate. The easiest way would be to have one master server and just have the second client straight up send and receive data to the master via sockets or whatever your favorite method of IPC is. Of course you can always just use one process and make it start 2 seperate windows that just act like consoles but aren't native consoles.

Comment: The term you're looking for is Inter-Process Communication, or IPC. Try Googling that, at least one of the methods should suit your needs.